# VSIX (Visual Studio Extension) "Fonts and Colors" changed event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am writing a Visual Studio 2012/2013 Extension and for performance reasons, all the configuration values are cached.

To make changes in "Fonts and Colors" visible in real-time i need to know, when the options where changed by the user.

Is there a way to be notified if any option settings were changed by the user?

At the moment I have a workaround and use the `Windows.WindowCreated` event in my Initialize method:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    new Action( () => {
        DTE.Events.WindowEvents.WindowCreated += WindowEvents_WindowCreated;
    } ), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, null );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the input. I think I found something useful. I have a `IWpfTextViewCreationListener`. I added following code lines:

```
[Import]
public IEditorFormatMapService FormatMapService = null; // MEF

public void TextViewCreated( IWpfTextView textView ) {
    IEditorFormatMap editorFormatMap = FormatMapService.GetEditorFormatMap( textView );
    editorFormatMap.FormatMappingChanged += FormatMapChanged;
}

void FormatMapChanged( object sender, FormatItemsEventArgs e ) {
    /* do something */
}
```

The `FormatItemsEventArgs` include all the changed fonts and colors. That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: public void TextViewCreated( IWpfTextView textView )

Who calls that?? How did you get the text view that you needed?? Why is this so freaking difficult to find a single working example of this!! MS docs are among the worst available and user content is almost non existent! How does anyone figure this stuff out???

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IVsTextManagerEvents.OnUserPreferencesChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextmanagerevents.onuserpreferenceschanged.aspx) event. See [VS Package - Receiving Option Fonts and Color Change Events](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8db35420-61f3-4f9d-9fd5-04687a914f75/vs-package-receiving-option-fonts-and-color-change-events?forum=vsx) for a code sample.

Comment: +1, I've personally used this to achieve exactly what the OP is looking for. Note that there's still bugs (in VS 2013) with getting a given colour from the font and colour storage service with the NOAUTOCOLORS option when the theme is changed and the colour is set to 'Automatic' -- for a workaround (that works!) see Josh's answer in the [forum thread on this issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ebbcd9dd-636f-47c3-9184-04acb921e181/vs-2012-package-supporting-dark-themes?forum=vsx)

Comment: I'm now hitting this issue again on VS2015 and 2017... Unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

The event you are looking for is `IEditorFormatMap::FormatMappingChanged`.  This will fire when a value in the "Fonts and Colors" section is changed.  This interface is specific to a particular `ITextView` instance but you could easily aggregate it over all `ITextView` instances that are created.

To get this interface you will need to import `IEditorFormatMapFactoryService`.  This service provides a mapping from `ITextView` -> `IEditorFormatMap`

Comment: These are my first steps with Visual Studio Extensions. A complete code example would be really useful.

Comment: @Flynn unfortunately a complete code sample is well beyond what I can fit in a stack overflow answer.  VS extension samples tend to be that way.  However you can start by looking at the following link.  These two files conspire to look at the exact event I mentioned.  https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VimWpf/Implementation/BlockCaret/BlockCaretFactoryService.cs  https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VimWpf/Implementation/BlockCaret/BlockCaret.cs

Comment: 'A complete code example' is maybe the wrong wording. I need only the basic structure (possibly using MEF) to get to this event. To get to the WindowCreated event I used: `DTE.Events.WindowEvents.WindowCreated += WindowEvents_WindowCreated;` Is there something like that to get to the Preferences Changed Event?

Comment: Thanks again, your answer gave me enough Information to find the correct answer.